# File Structure of a Div Javascript Class

Tags: javascript, html

Is this possible, and if so how is it done?

I do not want to use iframes.

I want to write the html of just a `div` in a separate file. I want to then insert this into my `body` of my html.

I then want to write a separate js file which operates the code in the `div`.

So my html file would look like this:

`mydivhtml.html` (It is just this html, no headers or body etc)

```
<div id="mydivhtml" style="width: 30vw; height: 100vh;">
    <button id="myButton" onclick="MyOnClick();"></button>
    <label id="myLabel"></label>
</div>
```

My js file would be a normal js file:

`mydivjs.js`

```
function MyOnClick(){
    document.getElementById("myLabel").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

Then when I wanted to use this, I include the js file as normal:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mydivjs.js"></script>
```

**But**, then I just add the html in some way.

I know people advise not to do `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<div>Hello!</div>";` because it will keep on firing `onload`.

So I want to do something like this:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.id = 'mydivhtml';
myDiv.innerHTML = "<button id=\"myButton\" onclick=\"MyOnClick();\"></button>"
                  "<label id=\"myLabel\"></label>";
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

**BUT** how do you do this from just the `mydivhtml.html` without having to write it out bit by bit?

Comment: you could load it in via AJAX

Comment: Thanks. But how would you add it to the body without the generally disliked: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<div>Hello!</div>";`

Comment: @Rewind look at the new answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if your directories is like this

```
Main -|
      |main.html
      |mydivhtml.html
      |mydivjs.js
```

then you should have this code on your `main.html`

```html
<script>

fetch("./mydivhtml.html").then(x=>x.text()).then(data =>{
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.id = 'mydivhtml';
    myDiv.innerHTML = data;
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
    // need to have mydivjs.js as a script
    var mydivjs = document.createElement("script")
    mydivjs.src ="./mydivjs.js"
    myDiv.appendChild(mydivjs)
})

</script>
```

hope it works...

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I had a phone call.